# How to modify a div with another div with Css

Tags: html, css, class

I want to change the `display:` from `none` to `block` in the div `drop` when you hover the cursor over the div `menu`.  I have tried using the characters `+`, `~`, `>`, `.`, and a space.  I have also tried using `id`s with `class`es, `id`s with `id`s, and `class`es with `class`es.  Here is the code for the

**CSS** and **HTML**

```css
#menu ol li:hover{
     color:yellow;
}
#menu ol{
     list-style:none;
     background-color:black;
     color:#11B594;
     padding:5px;
     width:40px;
     height:20px;
     text-decoration:none;
     display:block;
     margin:left;
     position:top;
     padding-top:5px;
}
#drop ul{
     list-style:none;
     background-color:grey;
     padding:5px;
     width:120px;
     height:60px;
     text-decoration:none;
     display:none;
     position:absolute;
     padding-top:5px;
    top:0px;
     left:55px;
}
#drop ul li:hover{
    background-color:#1DE5FC;
     padding:5px;
    }
#menu ol li:hover .drop ul{
     display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"> 
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"/>
  <title>
   Main page
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="menu">
   <ol>
    <li>
     <b>
      Menu
     </b>
    </li>
   </ol>
  </div>
  <div id="drop">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#.html" >#</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify that when you hover over `#menu (#menu:hover)` that you want the [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `#drop ul` to be visible `display:block;`.

Also, in order to avoid any "jumpiness", you'll also need to specify the same rule when hovering over the `#drop ul`.

```
#menu:hover + #drop ul,
#drop ul:hover {
  display:block;
}
```

```css
#menu ol li:hover
 {
  color:yellow;
 }
#menu ol
 {
  list-style:none;
  background-color:black;
  color:#11B594;
  padding:5px;
  width:40px;
  height:20px;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  margin:left;
  position:top;
  padding-top:5px;
 }
#drop ul
 {
  list-style:none;
  background-color:grey;
  padding:5px;
  width:120px;
  height:60px;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  padding-top:5px;
  top:0px;
  left:55px;
 }
#drop ul li:hover
 {
  background-color:#1DE5FC;
  padding:5px;
 }
#menu:hover + #drop ul,
    #drop ul:hover {
      display:block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"> 
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"/>
  <title>
   Main page
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="menu">
   <ol>
    <li>
     <b>
      Menu
     </b>
    </li>
   </ol>
  </div>
  <div id="drop">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#.html" >#</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot.